# Get the source of NuGet package

Tags: typescript, nuget, github-actions

I want for in a GitHub Action the Information of NuGet packages.
I want to collect all NugetPackages with Version and Source, just like it is written in the metafiles.

Unfortunately they (the metafiles) are outside of the repository by default.

How do I get automatically and independently the source (and Version) of a nuget package (in typescript)?

```
async function getAllNuGetPackages(projectList: string[], sourceList: string[]): Promise<{ AllNugetPackageInfo[] }> {
  const allPackages: AllNugetPackageInfo[] = [];

  for (const project of projectList) {
    for (const source of sourceList) {
      const output = child_process.execSync(`dotnet list ${project} package --source ${source}`);
      const lines = output.toString().split('\n');
      let name: string = '';
      let currentVersion: string = '';
      for (const line of lines) {
        if (line.includes('Project')) {
        } else if (line.includes('>')) {
          const parts = line.split(/ +/);
          name = parts[2];
          currentVersion = parts[3];
          allPackages.push({ project, source, name, currentVersion });
        }
      }
    }
    return allPackages;
  }
```

Thats my current function, but it does not work, even when I statically type the source (other than https//api.nuget.org/v3/index.json)

Please help me. I just need some hints or links or something like that to know, where the problem lies and what to do to solve this puzzle.